# What are the differences between programming in an IT department and a Product Development department?

Tags: development-environment

Our company has recently decided that a good section of our IT department is actually doing product development and not internal IT development and now has created a new department.

What are the types of changes that developers should be looking to make during this type of transition?

Is there really any difference between internal development and product development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I work with Jeff.]

As others have mentioned, **a key difference stems from the nature of the user**:

- **When developing internal applications,** you're typically dealing users from a single department or group who use a limited number of apps, and they're mostly a captive userbase.
- **When developing external products,** you're dealing with users who see the whole enchilada, and they're paying customers who can take their business elsewhere.

That difference matters because **a coherent user experience across multiple applications becomes much more important for paying customers** who see the entire set of apps.

- **In the IT case,** neither the business nor the users themselves are typically concerned about the fact that their app doesn't look and work like some other app that some other department uses. And if for whatever reason they did care, their ability to do anything about it is more limited. While it's possible to make a business case for consistency across apps (branding to internal employees, usability for employees who use multiple apps, reduced development costs resulting from the reuse of common libraries, patterns, services, etc.), this kind of concern typically takes a backseat to the development of new business functionality.
- **In the product case,** the users *do* care about coherence across the entire set of apps, and they *can* do something about it if the experience is weak.

So one major difference is the relative importance of a coherent, quality user experience. But that goal itself has significant **organizational ramifications** that we're already starting to see.

- We'll see **an increased emphasis on "horizontal" activities** that seek to establish standards and improve communications across teams, since such activities directly support the goal of producing coherent products. Cross-cutting teams (like user experience) will become more influential than they formerly were, we may see new cross-cutting teams (e.g. teams that look at architecture across many systems rather than just a single system), we'll probably see more presentations about what different apps do, more cross-training, etc.
- **App development teams will have less autonomy than they formerly had** in charting their own course. The user experience team (working with end users, business stakeholders and engineering teams) will specify standards around visual design, interaction design, etc. and the app teams will be expected to adopt those. We'll see test practices become more standardized. Builds and deployments across apps will be more uniform and coordinated. Monitoring, alerting, response time SLAs and other operational metrics will be more uniform across apps. The app teams won't be able to define these for themselves anymore (though they can certainly contribute to the larger discussion).
- Management will increasingly allocate resources in a way that seeks to **optimize globally across the entire product instead of optimizing locally for individual apps**. So where in the past the composition of individual app teams has been relatively fixed (developers, SQA, etc.), going forward we should expect to see more fluidity.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how quickly the differences will assert themselves in an existing group which is transitioning from one role to the other, but having worked as both an internal developer and a product developer, two **huge** differences leap to mind: requirements and and testing.

As a developer of internal tools, I was pretty much given free reign regarding interface, organization, and even scope.  Specs were in the form of an email saying "can you write something that does X?"  Similarly, testing was almost non-existent.  After whatever testing I was able to do, the tools would be deployed directly to their target audience and bug reports, when they came at all, were directly *from* those end-users, again usually via email or even hall-tackle.

Now that I'm doing product development, the difference is dramatic.  Specs are 30-100 page Word documents and we have a dedicated testing department which makes darn sure that what we produce *matches* those specs.  I'm much better supported by the project managers and have clear channels for any feedback I have on requirements or design.  It could be argued that product development offers less freedom to the individual developer, but in exchange for being part of a (hopefully) better-organized and better-supported team.

Answer (score 1):

A huge difference is in your customer.  IT developers have the rest of the company (and sometimes partner / subsidiary companies) as their primary customers.  The Product Development developers have customers (i.e. the people who buy the product that is the companies reason for existing) as the primary customer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very much so.  There's a huge difference between performing an activity that drives revenue and invoices and one that's perceived as overhead.

Answer (score 1):

My experiance is that people working on product development side of the house have bigger budgets, better training, better travel and more skilled employees.  Having worked in a product development company it always felt like the lower skilled employees were thrown over to IT department.

Comment: "bigger budgets, better training, better travel" - ha, that's a good one :-)

Answer (score 1):

In-house development is very process-orientated. They just want to deliver xyz functionality and have it work based on a company-wide strategy. It's not the iterative make-the-product better cycle you get when your primary product is your code. As a result, in-house stuff is often just 'good enough' whereas software companies probably tend to try to improve their product long after it 'just works'.

Note, in-house dev teams can get away with being 'good enough' but software development companies can get away with it for a *while* but will ultimately lose out to the ones who strive to improve.

I think moving between both environments could be a shock to the system in either direction but that's not to say they both can't be run in the same way - just that in my experience they probably won't. For example, UI is usually given a lower priority when it is in-house software as the customers are generally getting paid to use it rather than paying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I have been equals amounts of time in both types of organizations. The particular organization where I worked where the software development was part of an IT department treated the development of software as a cost center, where as software development as part of an product was seen as a profit center.

The two are very different. The skill level of developers in my case was vastly different-- those working on a public product were overall better skilled and cared more about the quality of their work. As a developer of a real public product you are actually making the company money.

In my internal software job I typically had a set of known fixed requirements mostly worked out. I designed a solution, but was always given a deadline that was unreasonable if quality was a concern (including code quality), rushed the coding, and delivered the result. Any bugs found that passed any short QA process typically only got fixed if they made formal requests for fixes.

Product development in my experience is almost the reverse.  All the requirements are not fixed (only what I was working on for that week was fixed), design is usually dictated by someone who has worked on the product the longest. I get decide how long something takes (but got to really explain why and justify the time), and coding is usually not rushed. Experimenting with ideas generally is more difficult in product development because a product that is meant for public use should use tried and tested approaches.

Therefore, I would say that if creativity is really important then product development may not be for you because a particular idea that you personally have is unlikely to ever make it into the product unless you can make a business case for it and somehow make it more important than what the business has already been planning.

Choosing a particular library is also more difficult depending on how the software is deployed. For example software used by the government typically has to pass Common Criteria certification, which can eliminate certain library choices.